# Conflict between google_maps_flutter and google navigation android sdk

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am having google_map_flutter package for my flutter app to show some markers of particular places .I also wanted to implement google navigation SDK and there is no Flutter package for that so I had to do it natively as follows:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.navigation:navigation:VERSION_NUMBER'
}
```

but I am always getting this error :

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

with many duplicates errors like this :
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate found in modules jetified-navigation-4.5.0-runtime (com.google.android.libraries.navigation:navigation:4.5.0) and jetified-play-services-maps-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory found in modules jetified-navigation-4.5.0-runtime (com.google.android.libraries.navigation:navigation:4.5.0) and jetified-play-services-maps-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0)

i had to add this as docs said:

```
allprojects {
   ...
   // Required: you must exclude the Google Play service Maps SDK from
   // your transitive dependencies. This is to ensure there won't be
   // multiple copies of Google Maps SDK in your binary, as the Navigation
   // SDK already bundles the Google Maps SDK.
   configurations {
       implementation {
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
       }
   }
}
```

now the google_map_flutter package complains i can not find google maps sdk like this:

error: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
^
/Users/mohammedabdelfattah/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_maps_flutter_android-2.4.15/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:24: error: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

I have been trying to exclude google map from the navigation sdk like this:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.navigation:navigation:4.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
```

but with no luck i am just looping.